# How to Query process names under low integrity process?

Tags: c++, windows, security, internet-explorer

I'm writing a BHO and I'd like to execute an external process.
If the OS is vista or greater the user may be in protected mode, making my BHO running under a low integrity process.

The external process I'm trying to execute is listed in the IE's Elvation Policy list making it running under normal integrity.

I'd like to check if the process is currently running and create it once only if it's not.
Problem is that I can't query a process with a higher integrity than mine
when i use :
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwPID);
I'm able to open only the processes that have low integrity.

Is there any other way to query process names from a low integrity process?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, what else could you do when you can call ReadProcessMemory()...

Comment: I wouldn't but I need it for EnumProcessModules and GetModuleBaseName. Is there another way to get process name without the VM_READ attribute? BTW I could use a mutex or something to check if the process exists but now I'm just curious. I think there's another way

Comment: Just fyi it _seems_ that .Net's Process.GetProcesses() will give the list even when running under low integrity. I'm not sure what it does under the hood but you could look into that.

Comment: Based on the .net code looks to me you can use NtQuerySystemInformation() from Kernel32 to retrieve it, and in my testing it appears to work from low-integrity processes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot solved it, it maps every process no matter what it's integrity.
The PROCESSENTRY32 struct has the executable file and that's all i needed.

Comment: I know this is old, but just as a heads up for everyone else, I think this might have been a loop hole that's been recently closed. I've noticed that IE 11 on Windows 10 in protected mode will only show processes at the same low integrity when using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.